# EditText in ListView Loses value when scroll up and down

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-edittext

I've input value in `EditText` in ListView but when I scroll up and down the values is not focus and lose. please help me. I am newbie.

I've tried `TextWatcher`, and saving data to `array`, but problems is that returned position of view in `ListView` is not always right, so I lost some data from array.

this is my code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private View itemView;
HashMap<String, String> Result = new HashMap<String, String>();
private Bitmap ImageCover;

private TextView bookname;
private TextView bookcode;
private TextView index;
private ImageView bookcover;
private String BookIDSend;
private String QtySend;
private EditText TxtStock;
private String[] valueList;
private boolean InputState;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, boolean state) {
    this.context    = context;
    data            = arraylist;
    valueList       = new String[data.size()];
    InputState      = state;
}
@Override
public int getCount() { 
    return data.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position; }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return position; }

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater    = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_list_item, parent, false);
        if ( ( position % 2 ) == 0 ) {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(250,235,215));
        } else {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,235,205));
        }
        Result                  = data.get(position);
        ClassFile FileName      = new ClassFile();
        String AppDirectory     = FileName.GetAppDirectory(context);
        String Directory        = AppDirectory+"/cover/";

        index                   = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numb);
        bookname                = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
        bookcode                = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.code_book_input);
        bookcover               = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCover);
        TxtStock                = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.EdtIsi);
        TxtStock.setText(Result.get(InputActivity.INITIAL_STOCK));

        final int pos   = position;
        valueList[pos]  = Result.get(InputActivity.INITIAL_STOCK);
        if (InputState){
            TxtStock.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            TxtStock.setEnabled(false);
        }
        TxtStock.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                valueList[pos] = s.toString().trim();
            }
        });
        bookname.setText(Result.get(InputActivity.BOOKNAME));
        bookcode.setText(Result.get(InputActivity.BOOK_CODE));
        ClassImage Procimg      = new ClassImage();
        ImageCover              = Procimg.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri( Directory + Result.get(InputActivity.BOOKCOVER), 90, 120);
        bookcover.setImageBitmap(ImageCover);
    }else {
        itemView    = convertView;
    }

    int j = position+ 1;
    index.setText("" + j);
    return itemView;
}
```

thx before

Comment: I would like to point out one mistake, in method getItem you have to return data[position].........`public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position]; }`

Comment: error sir. it said "the type of expression must be an array" @Ranjith

Comment: `return data.get(position);` data is an ArrayList.

Comment: nothing happened sir @iForests

Comment: Oh..my bad..i meant data.get[position]...@iForests thanks for correcting..

Comment: Just wanted to point out the mistake, it may not be related to the error you are getting...

Answer (score 0):

When the ListView is scrollered, it will call the method `getView()`, so you need to set the text to you EditText, so you need to do is:

`TxtStock.setText(valueList[pos]);`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly using EditText in ListView isn't a great idea! But if you have to do this you might give a try..

change you code like this..

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return data.get(position); }
```

and in the getView(..) method you're recycling the views and that's why you're losing your data. Make this change..

move this line `**TxtStock.setText(Result.get(InputActivity.INITIAL_STOCK));**
 to outside the if..else condition inside getView(..)

Hope this helps..Only findViewById when **convertView is null** and all other set methods should be called`outside the if..else condition when you're **recycling** the view. Thanks!! ;D